# Ionic 4 iOS scrolls TABS and not Content (header too)

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, tabs, ionic4

This happens only on iOS, in android the tabs are NON SCROLL-ABLE. the user can scroll the content, but also it scrolls the tabs and the header.

[click here to see video LINK](https://streamable.com/cbk3e)

meanwhile i have a menu that swipes from left to right side, it scrolls the content if i try two three times while if i catch the tabs it scrolls the TABS and if i try to scroll the CONTENT it keep SCROLLING THE TABS, HEADER TOO.

i have tried these two solutions, which it does not work for me:
[solution 1](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/18273)
[solution 2](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/18517)

on the Solution 2 i get the tabs non scroll-able but i dont get the content and nothing works, as i can see it can switch between the tabs but none of the contents does not work.
[see second video of not showing content with ion-toolbar outside ion-content](https://streamable.com/o26wm)

i have made two ion-tab-bar, one for activated profile with buttons enabled, and the other for disabled buttons for non activated profile.

**this is app.component.html code containing menu:**

**I also tried to add ion-split-pane, no success**

**this is tabs page with route:**

[SOMEHOW I COULD NOT PASTE CODE AS IT SHOULD, PLEASE CLICK HERE TO SEE THE CODES](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-4-ios-scrolls-tabs-and-not-content-header-too/181139)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put your tabs OUTSIDE the `ion-content`

Comment: with TABS outside the ION-CONTENT, the CONTENT DOES NOT SHOW UP AT ALL, it stays blank...

Comment: Could you check if you have some nested ion-content? Maybe in a component that you use inside a page...That was the problem for me

Comment: I did check, what worked for me was to put the <ION-TABS> outside of <ION-CONTENT> and outside of <ION-TOOLBAR> so ION TABS should be on its own, this way worked for me without any problem, thank you for your reply, as i have seen ion-toolbar is a solution also on many users so this should be marked as an ANSWER.